# How to add ink/ripple effect to an element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For example if I have an albums.jsx file in which I wrote:

```
import ripple from 'material-ui/ripple'
```

then in my element I can use:

```
return <div className={ripple}><div>
```

So that this div will have ink/ripple effect. This can be done in Angular Material via a class name, so I imagine there should be a similar feature in Material-UI/react-md

Answer (score 2):

You have to import it like this:

`import TouchRipple from 'material-ui/internal/TouchRipple';`

Then use in your component like this (`TouchRipple` is basically a higher-order component):

```
<TouchRipple>
   <div>
    MY RIPPLING DIV
  </div>
</TouchRipple>
```

If you need to solve the problem with `classNames` instead of a HOC, I suggest to use `react-materialize` -> https://react-materialize.github.io/#/

Comment: Thanks let me give it a try.